# Unable to convert System.Date and System.int to System.String, error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to search a keyword in the SQL Server db from `Textbox1` and printing the corresponding details in other TextBoxes.

While running the below code, it shows it is unable to convert the `DateTime` and `Integer` value into `String` to display it in the TextBoxes.

Also there is another `end of statement expected` error in the `command.Parameter` line:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-STMQUHM; Database = HospitalDB;Trusted_Connection=True")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from Medicines where MedicineName ='" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Textbox1",SqlDbType.Text)Value=TextBox1.Text 'Another error    
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""

    If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString
        TextBox2.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString
        TextBox3.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString
        TextBox4.Text = table.Rows(0)(4).ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("NO DATA FOUND!!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing a dot at: `command.Parameters.Add("@Textbox1",SqlDbType.Text)Value=TextBox1.Text` it should be: `command.Parameters.Add("@Textbox1",SqlDbType.Text).Value=TextBox1.Text`, though you haven't added a parameter named `Textbox1` to your query. Change it to: `select * from Medicines where MedicineName = @Textbox1` (no string concatenation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from Medicines where MedicineName ='" &  TextBox1.Text & "' ", connection)
command.Parameters.Add("@Textbox1",SqlDbType.Text)Value=TextBox1.Text
```

Into this:

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from Medicines where MedicineName = @MedicineName", connection)
command.Parameters.Add("@MedicineName",SqlDbType.Text).Value=TextBox1.Text
```

This is because you have not declared the parameter name into your original SQL string, then on the second line of your code, before `Value`, you're missing a dot.